# C# Portable Application vs .NET

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, exe, portability

I've a Win32 application written in C# via Visual Studio 2015 and I want to make it portable in order to avoid the installation of .NET framework everytime I deploy my application to clients.

I read this article: [the key point of making portable apps seems the use of mscorlib.dll](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/392308/Csharp-Portable-Exe-File)

This method doesn't work, at least for me, despite my effort. I must presume this is not the *real* way to build an application as portable...?

What are my other options in Visual Studio? Should I rethink my entire application to avoid the use of NET?

Comment: First use this tool and check your class library. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ConnieYau.NETPortabilityAnalyzer than you can read this article to convert your library http://geekswithblogs.net/imilovanovic/archive/2012/08/31/vs2012---how-to-manually-convert-.net-class-library-to.aspx

Comment: Google for .NET Native. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn584397(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Portable applications and packages still require .NET, but in a way you are not using the entire subset available in .NET, which makes it *portable* among different platforms (Windows Phone, Universal Apps, etc.).

As far as I know the only option you have to overcome the dependency on the .NET Framework, is by compiling your assembly in 'native', which will include all code necessary to run the app on its own.